# How to define an intermediate admin user as the default install profile on fresh drupal 7?

Tags: 7, users

When generating a new drupal site (multisite), I would like to define the default user profile as an admin user without acces to administration menu.

How can I create this new user as an install profile with default login infos, keeping at the same time the admin user?

Comment: Hi, :) This is not right way of editing your post. If you feel the answer by @KyleBrowning is helpful, approve that.  and If you have another question ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). But don't make your post [Chameleon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new role

```
$admin_role = new stdClass();
$admin_role->name = 'myadminwithoutmenuaccess';
user_role_save($admin_role);


//This will give them all perms
user_role_grant_permissions($admin_role->rid, array_keys(module_invoke_all('permission')));
```

Then you just revoke administration menu

```
 user_role_revoke_permissions($admin_role->rid, array $permissions = array('administration menu'))
```

if you need to get the $rid at a later time you can do 
[`user_role_load_by_name()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_role_load_by_name/7)